# How to prevent the deletion of files by cleaning apps?

Tags: android, cordova, persistence, device

I'm developing an **app** that records persistence files and photos in internal storage device.

When the user installs any *cleaning apps* and click to cleaning device, the application detects my files and delete them, causing an error the next time I run my **app**.

I would somehow "protect" my files so they can not be deleted by *cleaning apps*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you saving your files ? Where are you saving them ? Usually, such cleaner apps will only delete cache files, and not other files you save.

Comment: I'm saving with this plugin <https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/>, on cordova. It's saved on ~/ directory, in a file .db. All the photos are saved on a new directory created by my app.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?